# Returning json data from url with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am working on a simple app that returns one value from a json resource at certain url.
Although I've created a `vue.config.js` file to avoid CORS problem, still getting on execution the message:

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/xxx/37.8267,-122.4233' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
>   If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What am I missing? Thank you very much!

Location.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ forecast.timezone }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Location',
  props: {
    forecast: Array
  }
}
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <location v-bind:forecast="forecast" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Location from './components/Location.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Location
  },
  data() {
    return {
      forecast: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getTimeZone()
  },
  methods: {
    async getTimeZone() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/xxx/37.8267,-122.4233')
        const data = await response.json()
        this.forecast = data
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/xxx/'    
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how vue.config.js could fix you CORS issues. The server needs to respond to OPTION calls and allow further HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup CORS policy for external API. It's not related to `vue.js`.

Alternatively, if the external API is a 3rd-party API and you cannot change the CORS policy, then you can consume the external API in your server-side code and create your own API in your server-side code that will return whatever value you get from the external API.

Answer (score 0):

From Vue Cli docs:

> WARNING
>
> When devServer.proxy is set to a string, only XHR requests will be proxied. If you want to test an API URL, don't open it in the browser, use an API tool like Postman instead.

So, setting the devServer.proxy property, does not solve the issue, as api requests won't be proxied. For a permanent solution, as Circuit Breaker suggested, you have to allow the CORS request on the api server.